# Happy birthday 'for' or 'to' sb?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

Can I put 'for' after 'Happy birthday'? I don't know why it is not suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can when referring to the birthday boy or girl in the third person.

> Jane was out waterskiing, and somehow managed to crash into a dolphin and broke her wrist.  So, all in all, not a very happy birthday **for** poor Jane.

Otherwise, as with an other communication, when addressing a person directly you speak *to* them to wish them happy birthday.

> Let's all sing "happy birthday" **to** Jane, to make her feel better!